# MacOS: SecKeyCreateWithData fails with code 50

Tags: macos, openssl, private-key, pem

I've got the following Swift code below:

```
    let privString = "MHQCAQEEIEuXPCziDSJqCxpOHEhcg1sEm7EtEiH2XVvXK69DcUHroAcGBSuBBAAKoUQDQgAECDDYmcIpUxC2EVJu8o/qPHPoZMId11A/2nVAXJByFOYSigUnZ6njK4qZQMGxLr3xNND17yYoXZ21QKus4bUHfg=="

    let privData = NSData(base64Encoded: privString)
    let privRaw = privData?.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    let CFPrivData = CFDataCreate(nil, privRaw!, privData!.length)

    let options: [String: Any] = [kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECDSA,
                                  kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
                                  kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256]
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

    guard let privKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(CFPrivData!, options as CFDictionary, &error) else {
        throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
    }
```

The key is a PEM file with the headers stripped and the private key was generated with the following command

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -noout -out ngthnd_priv.pem
```

Comment: To clarify, Yes I know that this isn't a very secure way of working with a private key. I just want to play with the API a little and I'm currently stuck.